# How can I create a new JSON object consisting of parts of other JSON objects in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, json, post, get

I have a server that returns a JSON object like so:

```
object = {"name": "VM1", "load": .5" (assume there are other key/value pairs here, and before "name" as well...)}
```

I want to create a new JSON object for a POST that consists of just the name and load.

When I try something like:

```
testSend1 = json.dumps({})   
testSend1["name"] = "firstVM"
```

I get the error: "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment". Also, I'm having trouble comparing the loads as ints and accessing them from within my JSON object. Any ideas?

Comment: You have an extra quotation mark: `"testSend1["name"]` should be `testSend1["name"]`

Comment: That's just a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. Why error?

Because you are trying to assign value to a serialized JSON formatted stream. The server response may be in JSON stream format (not clear in the question). You need json.loads to de-serialize into Python object for such modification

Q2.

> I want to create a new JSON object for a POST that consists of just
>   the name and load. (Assume I need to create a new JSON object and
>   can't just cut off date).

If it is a throw away object, you can use **pop** method on python object.

After making necessary changes. You can call json.dumps to serialize it as JSON object.

Suggestion: Avoid using "object" as name :)

**Illustration:**

```
import json

response = {"name": "VM1", "load": .5, "date": "Tuesday"}
print "Initial Value :", response

response["name"]="firstVM1"
print "After modification :", response

response.pop("date")
print "After removing date :", response

print "After serializing.."
serialized_data = json.dumps(response)
print serialized_data

print "After de-seriali\ing..."
print  json.loads(serialized_data)

print "Attempting to modify serialized response"
serialized_data["name"] = "new VM"
```

Output:

```
Initial Value : {'load': 0.5, 'date': 'Tuesday', 'name': 'VM1'}
After modification : {'load': 0.5, 'date': 'Tuesday', 'name': 'firstVM1'}
After removing date : {'load': 0.5, 'name': 'firstVM1'}
After serializing..
{"load": 0.5, "name": "firstVM1"}
After de-seriali\ing...
{u'load': 0.5, u'name': u'firstVM1'}
Attempting to modify serialized response
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j.py", line 20, in <module>
    serialized_data["name"] = "new VM"
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: I'm really trying to add a key-value payer to an existing JSON object, or create a new one from scratch. Again, I can't just pop. How would I go about taking name and load and placing it into a new JSON object all together?

Comment: how deep is your JSON object?

Comment: Very shallow. Two or three fields.

Comment: Adding KV pair to an existing object is explained above. To create new object, just iterate thru comprehension {k:v for k,v in data.iteritems() if k not in filter_keys} or use deepcopy - very expensive though- and a pop. If this hasn't addressed ur original question still, please explain with a clear example